# JS String to html markup

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

Recently I wrote a simple webapp for handling telnet connections with routers. I am using Node.js with Express and WebSockets. After setting up a connection, a stream from terminal goes through websocket as UTF-8 string.

And here is my problem: I wrote a simple displaying function that uses `slice('\n')` and adds an html paragraph, but I'm not satisfied with results, everything is a mess (towel.blinkenlights.nl telnet-based Star Wars doesn't look even close to the version from terminal). When I display the data in the browser console it looks fine, but in my html it does not.

The main problem is probably caused by these all `\n`'s `\t`'s etc.

So now I'm looking for a solution/library/something that converts js string to html markup. Is there anything like that, maybe in jQuery or so?

Comment: Exactly what are you expecting, what are you seeing, and what is the code responsible for making you see it like you are?

Comment: saying something completely without seeing a single line of code is always difficult. What do you have? How does it look like currently? How is it supposed to look like?

Comment: Did you try just wrapping the text in PRE tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your text into a `pre` block and it will preserve formatting:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent = "string1\n\tstring2";


string1
    string2
```